# How to copy values to a list from a dictionary based on conditions from the dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a dataset (donor's choose) and I am trying to copy values from a dictionary to a list based on the class label.

Eg: My dataset has a column `[project_is_approved]` which is basically binary values **0 or 1**.

Each row also has a column named `[school_state]` which is basically a categorical feature with the state names`(eg: 'WV', 'NY' etc)`.

I also have two dictionaries with the probability values of each state if it belongs to a positive **class(1)** or a negative **class(0)**.

**{accepted_prob_clean_categories}** is a dictionary with the keys as the list of states and the values as probabilities only if it belongs to a positive class.

**{rejected_prob_clean_categories}** is a dictionary with the keys as the list of states and the values as probabilities only if it belongs to a negative class.

What I'm trying to do is that,

- I want to iterate over the entire dataset and if the
  'project_is_approved' value in a given row is 1
- I want to check the state in that particular row and append the
  probability value for that state from
  **{accepted_prob_clean_categories}** to a list
- The same applies to the negative class, except that the probability
  value is taken from **{rejected_prob_clean_categories}**

```
final_prob_clean_categories = []

mask = i['project_is_approved']
category = i.loc[mask,'school_state'].values
for i in X_train:
    if mask == 1:
        final_prob_clean_categories.append(accepted_prob_clean_categories[category])
    else:
        final_prob_clean_categories.append(rejected_prob_clean_categories[category])
```

I get an error as follows:

> "string indices must be integers'

```
accepted_prob_clean_categories = {}
{'AK': 0.8333333333333334,
 'AL': 0.860445205479452,
 'AR': 0.8321167883211679,
 'AZ': 0.848780487804878,
 'CA': 0.8565887714535053,
 'CO': 0.8295302013422818,
 'CT': 0.8615107913669064,
 'DC': 0.7959183673469388,
 'DE': 0.9004329004329005,
 'FL': 0.831678372487285,
 'GA': 0.8417372101582627,
'HI': 0.8606060606060606,
 'IA': 0.8493449781659389,
 'ID': 0.8299776286353467,
 'IL': 0.8522609596133932,
 'IN': 0.8541666666666666,
 'KS': 0.8382352941176471,
 'KY': 0.863013698630137,
 'LA': 0.8295384615384616,
 'MA': 0.8605678233438486,
 'MD': 0.8507905138339921,
 'ME': 0.8509316770186336,
 'MI': 0.8546132339235788,
 'MN': 0.8688118811881188,
 'MO': 0.8524203069657615,
 'MS': 0.8265895953757225,
 'MT': 0.8143712574850299,
 'NC': 0.8504589872668049,
 'ND': 0.9058823529411765,
 'NE': 0.8732394366197183,
 'NH': 0.865546218487395,
 'NJ': 0.8397606382978723,
 'NM': 0.8425414364640884,
 'NV': 0.8617256637168141,
 'NY': 0.8568246253543945,
 'OH': 0.8747002398081535,
 'OK': 0.8368841544607191,
 'OR': 0.8427230046948356,
 'PA': 0.8610445615716339,
 'RI': 0.8585365853658536,
 'SC': 0.8648134044173648,
 'SD': 0.8258706467661692,
 'TN': 0.8482456140350877,
 'TX': 0.8108108108108109,
 'UT': 0.8441330998248686,
 'VA': 0.8474452554744526,
 'VT': 0.7659574468085106,
 'WA': 0.8780332056194126,
 'WI': 0.8444084278768234,
 'WV': 0.8481375358166189,
 'WY': 0.8405797101449275}
```

rejected_prob_clean_categories is the complement of accepted_prob_clean_categories.

```
if my X_train is like this:

school_state   project_is_approved
AK                   1
AK                   0
CA                   0
CO                   1

I need values in final_prob_clean_categories as follows:
[0.8333,0.166666,0.14341,0.82953.....]etc
```

All these probability values are available in {accepted_prob_clean_categories} and {rejected_prob_clean_categories}

Comment: Please show an example of `accepted_prob_clean_categories`.

Comment: And please show the full stack strace so that we can know what line raised the exception.

Comment: The problem has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a Pandas Dataframe from you dictionaries, you can simply use a list comprehensive with the conditions you wish:

```
df["final_prob_clean_categories"] = [b if a == 0 else c for a, b, c in zip(df["project_is_approved"], df["rejected_prob_clean_categories"], df["accepted_prob_clean_categories"])]
```

This is similar to iterating each row of the dataframe and applying conditions, which is a slower process:

```
new_col = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['project_is_approved'] == 0:
        new_col.append(row["rejected_prob_clean_categories"])
    else: 
        new_col.append(row["accepted_prob_clean_categories"])
df["final_prob_clean_categories"] = new_col
```